# FileUploadField 'stuck' after submitting form with ExtJS4/DWR

Tags: file-upload, extjs4, dwr

im using extjs4 with dwr3 to upload a file

this is all i have in my form

```
{xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
name: 'file',
fieldLabel: 'Archivo', 
allowBlank: false,
buttonText: 'Seleccionar...' 
}, {
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Cargar',
action: 'cargarArchivo'
}
```

when i click the button (labeled Cargar) it submits the file and stays in the same page, so far so good. Problem is, when i choose another file, the text in the field stays the same instead of showing the new file chosen

this is what i have in my controller:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'NciImport button[action=cargarArchivo]': {
            click: this.cargaArchivo
        } 
    });
},

cargaArchivo : function (button){
    clickedButton = button;
    bsNciNiv.cargaArchivoNci(dwr.util.getValue('file'), function(x,y,z){
        clickedButton.up('form').down('fileuploadfield').createFileInput(); // funny solution
    });
}
```

The *bsNciNiv.cargaArchivoNci* part is my DWR service

the line i commented as *funny solution* kind of works, after adding it the rest works as expected, but i really dont think it is the right solution, just added it as a hint in case its useful

can anyone confirm if this is a bug or if theres a way to fix this? thanks

(btw not sure if this has anything to do with dwr3, but i tagged it anyway)

Comment: i am having trouble following what exactly are you trying to do on the button click event... add another fileupload field?

Comment: no, simply upload the file (ie submit the form). After succesfully doing so, the callback function is invoked. The createFileInput function, according to the docs, 'creates an invisible element that floats above the "Browse..." button to receive the clicks'. I think the problem is after submitting this invisible element no longer exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this component was not designed to upload multiple files (in series). 
The issue you are seeing is probably due to this hidden element not getting cleared: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-property-fileInputEl

You can probably file this as a bug with Sencha although they might consider it a feature :)

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this same problem using Ext-JS 4.1.1 and DWR3. I debugged the DWR javascript and found the cause. When the dwr method parameters include a fileupload field, dwr constructs a multipart post message and a hidden iframe rather than using XmlHttpRequest. As part of this process, it replaces the original fileupload element (this itself is a hidden element, created and managed by the Ext FileUpload component) with a clone (same ID and properties). As a result, the Ext field's fileInputEl property is no longer referring to the replaced element and the component's onFileChange() event handler is not registered for the new element's 'change' event. So, it isn't a bug in Ext-JS.

I worked around it in my callback like this:

```
var fileInputId = uploadField.fileInputEl.dom.id;

MyDwrService.fileUpload(uploadField.fileInputEl.dom, arg2, function(results) {
    uploadField.fileInputEl = Ext.get(document.getElementById(fileInputId));
    uploadField.fileInputEl.on({
        scope: uploadField,
        change: uploadField.onFileChange
    });
});
```

It worked for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE8